# Xamarin forms, how can I get the long, lat for a adress?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an entry (named adressEntry) where you write an adress. My question is how do I turn that adress into a long, lat?
This is my code so far, but the GetAdressesForPositionAsync does not let me enter the variable.

```
        var theEnteredAdress = adressEntry.Text;

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder ();
        Task<IEnumerable<Position>> result =
        gc.GetAddressesForPositionAsync (theEnteredAdress); //cannot enter the variable value here. Cannot convert string expression to type: Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (theEnteredAdress);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **have an address and you want to get a position** (for the address), you should be using [`Geocoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Geocoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync/p/System.String/), not `Geocoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync`.

```
var theEnteredAdress = adressEntry.Text;

Geocoder gc = new Geocoder();
IEnumerable<Position> result =
    await gc.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(theEnteredAdress);

foreach (Position pos in result)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Lng: {1}", pos.Latitude, pos.Longitude);
}
```

Comment: In the log I get the adressEntry.Text now (so the adress), i dont get the lat, long

Comment: Obvious question: is the address 1) correct, and 2) in an area the Geocoder has information on?

Comment: @medvedo well of course since you're using `Debug.WriteLine(theEnteredAddress)`

Comment: @medvedo See the answer now :)

Comment: @cubrr so where is the long, lat value stored?

Comment: @medvedo In the returned enumerable of `Position` objects.